# SQL: Select 2 tables without join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I wrote this SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    dbo.RDB_LOG_ITEM,
    (
        SELECT '000' + CAST(operatore as varchar) + cast(scontrino as varchar) search 
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                N0_XACT_NO scontrino,
                N0_OPERATOR_NO operatore
            FROM
                dbo.RDB_SCALE_ITEM
            WHERE
                BL_RECORD_EXPLODED = 0 AND
                N0_COUNTER_NO = 1 AND
                DT_TIME_STAMP LIKE '20160526%'
        ) db
    ) db2
WHERE
    DT_TIME_STAMP > '2016-05-26T00:00:00.000' AND
    SZ_SCALE_LABEL LIKE db2.search + '%'
```

But this query is executed in 3+ sec. The result of this query is a single row. The result of the select `db2` are only 7 rows.

I think when I use `from data1,db2` that SQL does a cross join (data1 is a big db with something like 300k+ rows) and slows the process.

If I try to write the select hard-coded with the result from the 2nd select I get the result in 0.01 sec like this: `select * from data1 where DT_TIME_STAMP > '2016-05-26T00:00:00.000' and SZ_SCALE_LABEL like '0001013530%'`

How can I use the `db2` without joining it with the other db?

edit

the subquery:

```
(
            SELECT '000' + CAST(operatore as varchar) + cast(scontrino as varchar) search 
            FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    N0_XACT_NO scontrino,
                    N0_OPERATOR_NO operatore
                FROM
                    dbo.RDB_SCALE_ITEM
                WHERE
                    BL_RECORD_EXPLODED = 0 AND
                    N0_COUNTER_NO = 1 AND
                    DT_TIME_STAMP LIKE '20160526%'
            ) db
        ) db2
```

give me X rows like

```
0001013530
0001013531
0001013532
0001013533
0001013534
```

what i need is a query like this `select * from dbo.RDB_LOG_ITEM where DT_TIME_STAMP > '2016-05-26T00:00:00.000' and (SZ_SCALE_LABEL like '0001013530%' or  SZ_SCALE_LABEL like '0001013531%' or  SZ_SCALE_LABEL like '0001013532%' or  SZ_SCALE_LABEL like '0001013533%' or SZ_SCALE_LABEL like '0001013534%')`

i think is something near the subquery IN http://www.dofactory.com/sql/subquery but with the LIKE

PS sorry for the incomplete post but i was at work and they was kicking me for close :-)

Comment: Please format your query.  It doesn't look like a single query to me.  Also add a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: The dbo. bit makes it look like SQL Server to me, but the submitter should tag it to be sure (and for politeness).  Also, it would make the life of anyone answering this a bit easier if you included the query execution plan.

Comment: Could you show us the schemas for the two tables, and especially their indexes? Also please show us the join query you tried. Also the result of the `explain` from the two queries (the join vs the sub-select).

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be using explicit `JOIN`s. Your `WHERE` clause should not have more than one table (in this case, considering the subquery as a "table").

Second, there is no need for a subquery here at all. You need to get out of the habit of leaning on subqueries and think in a set-based way when writing SQL.

Finally, use your aliases to prefix all of your columns in a query. It's impossible to tell where some of these columns are coming from without prefixing them.

I believe that this will get you the same results and will ideally be done in a performant way. If it's not, then you will need to post the full table structures (including indexes) as well as the query plans for anyone to be able to help you with performance issues.

```
SELECT
    LI.dt_time_stamp,
    LI.sz_scale_label,
    <list other columns here, because we **never** use SELECT *>
FROM
    dbo.RDB_LOG_ITEM LI
INNER JOIN dbo.RDB_SCALE_ITEM SI ON
    SI.bl_record_exploded = 0 AND
    SI.no_counter_no = 1 AND
    SI.dt_time_stamp LIKE '20160526%' AND  -- You should be using date datatypes for your date columns
    LI.sz_scale_label LIKE '000' + CAST(operatore AS VARCHAR(20)) + cast(scontrino AS VARCHAR(20)) + '%'    -- I guessed on appropriate VARCHAR sizes, which you should have
WHERE
    LI.dt_time_stamp > '2016-05-26T00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: i don't need to use a join

Answer (score 0):

How much data does your tables have? If they have huge data, without join your execution time will be more. I had similar experience. Using join reduced my execution time significantly.